# Setting font colour of outgoing emails in Mac Mail

Tags: mail.app, automator, font, shortcuts-app

It is not possible to set a default colour, other than black, for outgoing email messages in Mac Mail (MacOS).  Within Mail there are preferences for font and font size, but changing default colour is not an option.  Many will read this and say, *"but it's pointless changing colour of outgoing email text because you can't control how your email is rendered at the recipient's side"*.  While that is partly true, I would argue it's more true that styling would be rendered as the author has intended, assuming it's just font, colour and size.

There is a tedious work around using an already styled signature, it is highly unreliable and often random words will revert to being black so in the end it in fact involves more clicks and editing compared to just highlighting every email I send and changing the colour manually.

It finally came to me that it may be possible to set up a keyboard shortcut and an Automator macro, or something with Apple Shortcuts.  Something along the lines of:

- highlight text above specific and recurring link in default
  signature
- Click colour list from toolbar
- Click desired colour from colour list
- Click in body of text to unhighlight selection

I've just spent the best part of two hours trying to figure this out and regrettably didn‘t make a lot of progress.

So how can I use existing scripting functionality to format a mail?

Comment: Mail’s preferences for font and font size also do not set defaults for outgoings, they only affect what is seen locally.

Comment: @TomGewecke Thanks for your comment - you've stated the font settings 'only' affect what is seen locally.  But that is categorically untrue.  Of course, it's not 'never' true, but for the most part the font, size and colour of the text that I send someone will be rendered as such on their device.  There will be times when a receiver has set their device to render all emails in a specific way - but this is the exception, not the rule.  Regrettably your comment suggests that my question is futile and it's nothing of the sort.  Are you able to suggest on the use of macros, perhaps?  Thanks

Comment: Can you add some details about the Shortcut or AppleScript you already have, even if it doesn‘t fully work yet?

Comment: My comment was about what you do with Font and Font Size in Mail PREFERENCES. They only affect what you see locally. For something to be seen by the recipient you have to make your settings in the New Message pane for each message. Do you find otherwise?  My point is that your scripting fix needs to cover font name and font size as well as the color.

Comment: @TomGewecke Ah I see, I misunderstood.  And you are right, though there is some deception by Apple going on.  It 'seems like' that the font you choose in preferences is the font that is 'sent', but those settings do seem to only affect things locally.  It may say Verdana 30 even in the New Message pane, but unless you actively choose another font and size and then revert to your specified choice of Verdana 30, it won't actually send as that.  As you've said, a scripting fix would in fact need to choose a wrong font and size, then the right font and size...and colour before being sent...!

Comment: Thank you @nohillside, but my problem is I don't even have a starting point.  I've never used scripts or Shortcuts before.  I just assumed they would be the right things to use in this instance, but after experimentation I just couldn't get anything working.  It was at that point of utter failure that I succumbed to asking for help!!

Comment: I feel the OP's pain. I'm disappointed about this.